# This while loop wont run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I've been doing some basic practice exercises for python, and so far it has been quite smooth flowing and such though I've run into a problem where the second while loop will not run. So far I've re-indented, defined the whole second and tried putting parameters on the loop where done = True, while done == True:, done = False
(later on in the code was what I previously had down but I removed it in effort to get it working.)

P.S some advice on my code would be greatly appreciated if you feel it necessary, as tbh I'm just winging it as I've been teaching myself how to code in python.  I've included the first while loop too, as I figured that far down the code may be cause for the problem unknowingly.

```
import random
Olist = []
while True:
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
print("\nWelcome to exercise 05")
InH1 = str(input("\nDo you wish to continue? (y/n):"))
if InH1 == 'y':
    list1 = random.sample(range(30), 11)
    list2 = random.sample(range(30), 9)
    print("\n<><>Two random lists have been generated.<><>")
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    max_index = len(list2)-1
    print("\n<><>Max index has been generated.<><>")
    InD = str(input("\nStart the func? (y/n):"))
    if InD == 'n':
        break
    if InD == 'y':
        while True:
            if counter2 == 11:
                print(Olist)
                InL = str(input("\nEnter any key to return to the start of the program,\
                                  or,\n enter 'q' to break the program."))
                if InL == 'q':
                    break
            if list1[counter2] == list2[counter]:
                Olist.append(list2[counter])
                counter + 1
            elif counter == 10:
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter + 1
if InH1 == 'n':
    break
```

Comment: improve your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few details:

- there is no action on `counter2` after you assign `counter2 = 0` so you will never enter the `if counter2 == 11` branch [unreachable] and - unless needed somewhere else - you can completely remove that part
- as said by Tom you have to ask the counter increment as `counter = counter + 1` or with the short form `counter += 1`
- you have to control also that `counter` doesn't get over the `max_index` or you will try to fetch an unexisting element in the array generating an `"IndexError: list index out of range"` from the `if list1[counter2] == list2[counter]` line before `counter` can be reset by the following `elif` branch
- you need to create a condition to stop the second loop or you will not come to an end of the program: this is why I modified it into `while counter < max_index:`: the same line will allow you to safely remove the `elif` branch of the previous point too
- I left the first loop constantly running to start over indefinitely

This code should be fine for your target:

```
import random
Olist = []

while True:
    counter = 0
    counter2 = 0
    print("\nWelcome to exercise 05")
    InH1 = str(input("\nDo you wish to continue? (y/n):"))

    if InH1 == 'y':
        list1 = random.sample(range(30), 11)
        list2 = random.sample(range(30), 9)
        print("\n<><>Two random lists have been generated.<><>")
        print(list1)
        print(list2)
        max_index = len(list2)-1
        print("\n<><>Max index has been generated.<><>")
        print(max_index)
        InD = str(input("\nStart the func? (y/n):"))
        if InD == 'n':
            break
        if InD == 'y':
            print(list1[counter2])
            print(list2[counter])
            while counter < max_index:
                if counter2 == 11:
                    print(Olist)
                    InL = str(input("\nEnter any key to return to the start of the program,\
                                  or,\n enter 'q' to break the program."))
                    if InL == 'q':
                        break
        
                if list1[counter2] == list2[counter]:
                    Olist.append(list2[counter])
                    counter += 1
                else:
                    counter += 1

    if InH1 == 'n':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
while True:
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
```

`counter = 0` is ***OUTSIDE*** of the while-loop

Did you want the following?

```
while True:
   counter = 0
   counter2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if list1[counter2] == list2[counter]:
                Olist.append(list2[counter])
                counter + 1
            elif counter == 10:
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter + 1
```

I think your `counter + 1` statements are causing you serious trouble.  Really take a close look there...  Don't you mean  `counter = counter + 1`?

Comment: I seriously missed that, cheers for the help there...clearly I can't review my code properly. Thanks for the comment Tom.